# PHP: Vim help file renderer for PhD (The [PH]P based [D]ocbook renderer)?

Tags: php, vim, docbook

I'm trying to add latest PHP reference into vim doc, but I can't find any scripts solving this problem (lots of outdated, but it seems no one is actually interested in doing that).

My idea is: get latest doc trunk and build it as usually with vim renderer, but I can't find any manuals on how to write renderers for PhD.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please refrain from making rude/offensive comments of this nature in the future.  Failure to do so may result in further moderator action.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no documentation about writing renders for PhD, but there's a package (IDE) that has simple renders for different formats (json, xml, sqlite) and you can easily [extend](http://git.php.net/?p=phd.git;a=tree;f=phpdotnet/phd/Package/IDE).

Also, this [blog post](http://bjori.blogspot.com.br/2010/01/unix-manual-pages-for-php-functions.html) explains how to integrate Vim with the PHP Manual manpages, not exactly what you want, but may help.